# memory issue in akka application

Tags: performance, scala, akka, actor

We have an application in Akka and having a problem with increasing heap memory that is growing with time and eventually crashing the application. On analyzing the heap dump we can see all our log entries are getting persisted in the memory. Below is object tree for the same

Akka dispatcher --> Unbounded mail box --> concurrent linked queue --> envelop object consisting of all the log information

Our actors are untyped actor and we are using akka default event logger for logging

Any idea what could be the problem with this?

Comment: When you analyze the dump, where do you see the memory is being used up? maybe the linked queue is not being emptied for some reason? If seems unlikely, but if the app is that simple I don't see any other place the memory could go

Comment: the app is a full fledged clusterd production application service, so I wont say it is simple. The linked queue is used by unbounded mailbox internally by akka, so not sure what is the mechanism for emptying it.